# Miktex console package manager couldn't resolve proxy name

Tags: miktex

I have been running Miktex on an older machine (with an older version) for years with no problems and wanted to get the ``latest and greatest'' for a new computer running Windows 7.

Just installed Miktex 2.9 (Console 2.9.6637), everything works just fine except: When running the update for automated package download I got "couldn't resolve proxy name." as the error message.

No remedy on the Miktex FAQs that I can find.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try without using a proxy?

Comment: I will have to check with my sysadmin, but I believe that I do have to use a proxy.

Comment: Also thanks for the warm welcome! I've been poking around here, and it looks like a great forum. There was a comment that looked related, and I tried modifying the environment variable  using set MIKTEX_MPM_REMOTESERVICE6100=multiplexor which did not seem to lead to a functional update feature and the error switched to "SSL connect error" ...

Comment: So, in order to address the issue, I uninstalled all of the Miktex build, and re-installed. This time the error is "Couldn't connect to server" ...

Comment: Reinstalled again, and now back to the SSL connect error.

Comment: As a work-around, I suggest you copy  the contents of a repository on a USB key (or on your hard disk), and  update from a local repository.

Comment: Bernard: That is a good idea. I am also going to try to use a different internet connection. Something I read on another thread.